# Modulo loop fails at 23 factorial

Tags: python-3.x, factorial

The below code works all the way to 22! but fails for 23!.

Can you see any rounding occurring anywhere that would cause an unexpected result?

What it does:
findprimes -->Returns a list of prime numbers
factor--> computes "num!'  (a factorial)
breakdown-->  returns a string (an equation) showing a product of prime numbers equal to the result of the factorial

```
def findprimes(num):
    nonprimes=[0,1]
for i in range(num+2):
    for k in range((i)):
        if(i+2)%(k+2)==0:
            nonprimes.append(i+2)
return [c for c in range(i) if c not in set(nonprimes)]

def factor(num):
    factorial=1
    for i in range(num):
        factorial=factorial*(i+1)
    return factorial

def breakdown(num):
    answer=[]
    iter_me=findprimes(num)
    remains=factor(num)
    for i in range(len(iter_me)):
        k=0
        tot=0
        while remains%iter_me[i]==0:
            remains=int(remains/iter_me[i])
            k+=1
        if k>1:
#            print(k)
            answer.append(str(str(iter_me[i])+'^'+str(k)+' * '))
        else:
            answer.append(str(str(iter_me[i])+' * '))

    return ''.join(answer).rstrip('* ')


#breakdown lower that 23 works!!!
print(breakdown(23))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: A wrong answer :)

Comment: print(breakdown(25)) should return "2^22 * 3^10 * 5^6 * 7^3 * 11^2 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23"

Answer (score 1):

```
>  remains=int(remains/iter_me[i])
```

should be

```
remains=int(remains//iter_me[i])
```

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: `//` means [floor division](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/5384587e52f863dcb8001c82) in python, which means it will round _down_. For example `10 / 4 = 2.5` vs `10 // 4 = 2`. So, when OP said that it only works for numbers less than 23 I had a feeling it had something to do with the division. Perhaps someone else can explain exactly why this matters...

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Although I am not convinced myself with the "why it works".

Comment: @LeeGaines: I know what `//` means, but `int()` also does floor, so should be redundant.  In other words, `int(10/4)` is 2, just as `int(10//4)` is 2.

Comment: on the first iteration: 

`x_remains = 7755605021665493027651584` with `/`

`y_remains = 7755605021665492992000000` with `//`

`int(x_remains) == int(y_remains)` returns `False`

Comment: I see, so it's not because of floor, but because the code requires "big integer" precision beyond the 15 digits of precision provided by 64-bit floating point.  Nothing to do with floor, everything to do with the output type.

Comment: hmmm. so why do you think floor returns the desired output?